# .htaccess : if is an path, do nothing, else, do the rewriterule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a little question very simple this time I think...
How Have I to write my htaccess to do this instructions :

IF IS "/uploads" PATH INTO MY REQUEST, NOT REDIRECT AT ALL, JUST DO THE REGULAR REQUEST
ELSE DO THE REWRITERULE : RewriteRule (.*) http://theDestinationDomain.com/$1 [P,L]

I Have tested that :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUST_URI} !^/uploads/(.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} theDomainThatWillBeRedirect.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://theDestinationDomain.com/$1 [P,L]
```

That Just don't work... That make always the redirection to theDestinationDomaine.com/...

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot !

See you

Olivier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note the extra E. :)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/uploads/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} theDomainThatWillBeRedirect.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://theDestinationDomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Work ! Great. Thanks a lot ! Finaly just an very simple condition. See you. Have a nice weekend